# Accessing certificate keystore

Tags: compact-framework, x509certificate, windows-mobile-6

How can I access a certificate stored in Windows Mobile 6, through .net compact framework, I mean?

Is there something that reminds Capicom?

Comment: "Access" how?  You want to enumerate/add certificates?  You want to extract them?  Use them for hashing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Compact Framework did not implement the X509Cerificate namespace.  Yes, it exists in the BCL, but all of my testing indicates that there's really no implementation behind it (at least nothing useful).

We recently had need to do certificate enumeration and importing on a device and we implemented it by P/Invoking [`CertOpenStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms937683.aspx), [`CertEnumCertificatesInStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms937636.aspx), [`CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925079.aspx) et al, which we rolled into the SDF and [it's available in the latest release](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx).

We did not implement hashing, etc. because we simply didn't need it at the time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you here but how do I purchase the standard or professional editions of the SDF? There is no link on that page.